# Adding a text box to the bottom margin area for the title page

Tags: pdftex, margins, documentclass-writing

I am trying to form a class file for our journal. I must add a text box which contains some information about press to the bottom margin area for title page. But I didn't get the result I wanted in my experiments. My result is as follows;

[image]

My MWE is like this;

```
% test.tex
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[super,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{abstract}
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\small}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Any configuration that should be done before the end of the preamble:
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=1cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,includehead,includefoot,showframe}
\setlength{\columnsep}{6mm} % Column separation width
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Configuration %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{Article Title}

\author{An Author}

\newcommand{\abstractText}{\noindent\lipsum[4]}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{textblock}{185}(20,272)
    \noindent\rule{0.92\textwidth}{0.3mm}
    \noindent\fbox{%
        \parbox{0.9\textwidth}{%
        \vspace*{1mm}%
        {\footnotesize
        \textbf{E-mail:\,}author@gmail.com\\
        \textbf{Submitted:\,}00.00.0000
        \,\textbf{\,Revision Received:\,}00.00.0000
        \,\textbf{\,Accepted:\,}00.00.0000
        \,\textbf{\,Published Online:\,}00.00.0000}
      }
    }
\end{textblock} 
    %%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Abstract %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \twocolumn[
    \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
        \maketitle
        \begin{abstract}
            \abstractText
            \newline
            \newline
        \end{abstract}
    \end{@twocolumnfalse}
    ]
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%
    % Article %
    %%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \section{Section Title 1}
    
    This is the first sentence\cite{ref1}.
    
    \section{Section Title 2}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque\footnote{First footnote}. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat\cite{ref2}. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus\cite{ref3}. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum\footnote{Second footnote}.
    
    \section{Section Title 3}
 
    \lipsum[2]
    \subsection{Section Title 3.1}
    \lipsum[3]
    \nocite{*}
    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% References %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
    \bibitem[Ref1, (2003)]{ref1} Ref1 journal, 2003
    \bibitem[Ref2, (2006)]{ref2} Ref2 journal, 2006
    \bibitem[Ref3, (2009)]{ref3} Ref3 journal, 2009
\end{thebibliography}   
\end{document}
```

In this example, I used `textpos` package to show what I want. But I do not want to use this package. Because this type of usage overlays the box over the margin area not inserting to above page number. This setting should be only for title page not for others.

How can I do this type of adjustment?

---

**My trial**

It's very sad that no one is responding. I'm sure there is someone who knows the answer to this. I made some experiments with `afterpage` package, but I still couldn't get the result I wanted.

My changed code is beloe;

```
% test.tex
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[super,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{abstract}
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\small}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Any configuration that should be done before the end of the preamble:
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=1cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,includehead,includefoot,showframe}
\setlength{\columnsep}{6mm} % Column separation width
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}

%------------------- these are added ---------------------------
\usepackage{afterpage}
\newcommand{\tpshrink}{
    \makeatletter
    \addtolength{\textheight}{-10mm}
    \addtolength{\footskip}{10mm}
    \makeatother
}

\newcommand{\tprestore}{
\makeatletter
\addtolength{\textheight}{10mm}
\addtolength{\footskip}{-10mm}
\makeatother
}
%------------------- these are added ---------------------------

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Configuration %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{Article Title}

\author{An Author}

\newcommand{\abstractText}{\noindent\lipsum[4]}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
\tpshrink  % <----------------  this is used to shrink title page -----------------
\begin{document}
    
\begin{textblock}{185}(20,261.5)
    \noindent\rule{0.92\textwidth}{0.3mm}
    \noindent\fbox{%
        \parbox{0.9\textwidth}{%
        \vspace*{1mm}%
        {\footnotesize
        \textbf{E-mail:\,}author@gmail.com\\
        \textbf{Submitted:\,}00.00.0000
        \,\textbf{\,Revision Received:\,}00.00.0000
        \,\textbf{\,Accepted:\,}00.00.0000
        \,\textbf{\,Published Online:\,}00.00.0000}
      }
    }
\end{textblock} 
    %%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Abstract %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \twocolumn[
    \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
        \maketitle
        \begin{abstract}
            \abstractText
            \newline
            \newline
        \end{abstract}
    \end{@twocolumnfalse}
    ]
    
    \afterpage{\aftergroup\tprestore}  % < ---- this used to restore to the default BUT NOT WORKING!!!!!!   
    %%%%%%%%%%%
    % Article %
    %%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \section{Section Title 1}
    
    This is the first sentence\cite{ref1}.
    
    \section{Section Title 2}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque\footnote{First footnote}. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat\cite{ref2}. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus\cite{ref3}. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum\footnote{Second footnote}.
    
    \section{Section Title 3}
 
    \lipsum[2]
    \subsection{Section Title 3.1}
    \lipsum[3]
    \nocite{*}
    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% References %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
    \bibitem[Ref1, (2003)]{ref1} Ref1 journal, 2003
    \bibitem[Ref2, (2006)]{ref2} Ref2 journal, 2006
    \bibitem[Ref3, (2009)]{ref3} Ref3 journal, 2009
\end{thebibliography}   
\end{document}
```

In this trial, when I used the `\tpshrink` command and comment `\afterpage{\aftergroup\tprestore}` line, I get exactly what I want for the first page, but the next page doesn't get it right.

[image]

`afterpage` command is not working correctly. It should restore the page setting after page break, but it is not working.

How should this be adjusted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be to do with `twocolumn`. You need to call `\afterpage` at the beginning of the second column.

To do this, I hooked into the end of the abstract and called `\afterpage` twice (I couldn't make it work before the abstract for some reason).

I switched to using `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry` to set the first page margins and then revert to default for the rest of the document, rather than using the primitives.

I don't think using `textpos` is terrible once you have the margins sorted out.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Any configuration that should be done before the end of the preamble:
\usepackage[super,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=1cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,footskip=1cm,includehead,includefoot,columnsep=6mm,showframe}

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{abstract}
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\small}

\newcommand{\maketitleandabstract}{%
  \twocolumn[
    \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
      \maketitle
      \begin{abstract}
        \abstractText
        \newline
        \newline
      \end{abstract}
    \end{@twocolumnfalse}
  ]
  \afterpage{\aftergroup\adjfootskip}%
  \begin{textblock}{185}(20,261.5)
    \noindent\rule{17cm}{0.3mm}

    \noindent\fbox{%
      \parbox{0.9\textwidth}{%
        \vspace*{1mm}%
        {\footnotesize
          \textbf{E-mail:\,}\@email\\
          \textbf{Submitted:\,}\@submitted
          \,\textbf{\,Revision Received:\,}\@revisionreceived
          \,\textbf{\,Accepted:\,}\@accepted
        \,\textbf{\,Published Online:\,}\@publishedonline}
      }
    }
  \end{textblock} 
}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\newcommand*{\adjfootskip}{\afterpage{\aftergroup\restoregeometry}}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \newgeometry{top=1cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,footskip=2.5cm,includehead,includefoot}
}

\newcommand*{\email}[1]{\gdef\@email{#1}}
\newcommand*{\submitted}[1]{\gdef\@submitted{#1}}
\newcommand*{\revisionreceived}[1]{\gdef\@revisionreceived{#1}}
\newcommand*{\accepted}[1]{\gdef\@accepted{#1}}
\newcommand*{\publishedonline}[1]{\gdef\@publishedonline{#1}}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Configuration %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{Article Title}

\author{An Author}

\email{author@gmail.com}
\submitted{00.00.0000}
\revisionreceived{00.00.0000}
\accepted{00.00.0000}
\publishedonline{00.00.0000}

\newcommand{\abstractText}{\noindent\lipsum[4]}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Abstract %
%%%%%%%%%%%%

\maketitleandabstract

%%%%%%%%%%%
% Article %
%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Section Title 1}

This is the first sentence\cite{ref1}.

\section{Section Title 2}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque\footnote{First footnote}. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat\cite{ref2}. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus\cite{ref3}. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum\footnote{Second footnote}.

\section{Section Title 3}

\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Section Title 3.1}

\lipsum[3]
\nocite{*}
    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% References %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
    \bibitem[Ref1, (2003)]{ref1} Ref1 journal, 2003
    \bibitem[Ref2, (2006)]{ref2} Ref2 journal, 2006
    \bibitem[Ref3, (2009)]{ref3} Ref3 journal, 2009
\end{thebibliography}   
\end{document}
```

#### First page

[image: p1output]

#### Second page

[image: p2output]

Comment: thanks a lot @DavidPurton for your suggestion. But when I compile your latex code with Texstudio, the second page doesn't look like what you show? Bottom margin is still wide. Is it compiler difference?

Comment: @Bluerose, assuming you're definitely sure you correctly copied and pasted the code, you can do some checks by putting `\listfiles` on the first line of your file. This will give you versions of every file. I'm running `LaTeX2e <2022-11-01>`, L3 programming layer <2022-11-02> and the newest package listed is `hyperref` (and related packages) from `2022-11-13`. There may be updates since then i don't have as I use the Debian version of TeXLive

Comment: I tested with all three engines and output is same with each too.

Comment: It also works on a new project created in Overleaf.

Comment: Yes you are right, I tested again in Overleaf, It is OK. Thanks again.