# Why doesn't the bottom margin setting change in a column mode?

Tags: pdftex, margins, titles

I am using article.cls for my latex template. I add a date info box to the bottom margin of the title page and set the text height as described at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/670037/120857. When I used two column mode, everything is OK.

### Two column output

[image: twocolumn output]

Footnotes and page number remain in place. But when I passed to one column mode, footnotes and page number are misplaced as shown below.

### one column output

[image: one column output]

Although the page layouts are drawn correctly, **why does this setting change incorrectly?** I would like to thank any friends who will make the smallest contribution for a solution.

My MWE is as follow:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}   %<----- two column mode
%\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, onecolumn]{article}   %<----- one column mode
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

% Any configuration that should be done before the end of the preamble:
\usepackage[super,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=1cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,footskip=1cm,includehead,includefoot,columnsep=6mm,showframe}

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{abstract}
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\small}

\newcommand{\maketitleandabstract}{%
    \twocolumn[    %< -------  in one column mode, this line is commented out
    \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
        \maketitle
        \begin{abstract}
            \abstractText
            \newline
            \newline
        \end{abstract}
    \end{@twocolumnfalse}
    ]  %< -------  in one column mode, this line is commented out

    \begin{textblock}{185}(20,263)
        \noindent\rule{17cm}{0.4mm}\vspace*{0.5mm}
        
        \noindent\fbox{%
            \parbox{0.9\textwidth}{%
                \vspace*{1mm}%
                {\footnotesize%
                    \textbf{E-mail:\,}\@email\\
                    \textbf{Submitted:\,}\@submitted
                    \,\(\bullet\)\,\textbf{Revision Received:\,}\@revisionreceived
                    \,\(\bullet\)\,\textbf{Accepted:\,}\@accepted}
            }
        }
    \end{textblock} 
}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\newcommand{\shrinkthepage}{%
\addtolength{\textheight}{-10mm}%
\addtolength{\footskip}{10mm}%
}     
\newcommand{\enlargethepage}{%
    \addtolength{\textheight}{10mm}%
    \addtolength{\footskip}{-10mm}%
}
\newcommand{\restorethepage}{\afterpage{\aftergroup\enlargethepage}}
% hook to shrink text area at start of document
\AtBeginDocument{\shrinkthepage}
% hook to expand text area on page following end of keywords env
\AddToHook{env/abstract/after}{\afterpage{\aftergroup\restorethepage}}

\newcommand*{\email}[1]{\gdef\@email{#1}}
\newcommand*{\submitted}[1]{\gdef\@submitted{#1}}
\newcommand*{\revisionreceived}[1]{\gdef\@revisionreceived{#1}}
\newcommand*{\accepted}[1]{\gdef\@accepted{#1}}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Configuration %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{Article Title}

\author{An Author}

\email{author@gmail.com}
\submitted{00.00.0000}
\revisionreceived{00.00.0000}
\accepted{00.00.0000}

\newcommand{\abstractText}{\noindent\lipsum[4]}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}

\begin{document}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Abstract %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \maketitleandabstract
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%
    % Article %
    %%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \section{Section Title 1}
    
    This is the first sentence\cite{ref1}.
    
    \section{Section Title 2}
    
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque\footnote{First footnote}. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat\cite{ref2}. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus\cite{ref3}. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum\footnote{Second footnote}.
    
    \section{Section Title 3}
    
    \lipsum[2]
    
    \subsection{Section Title 3.1}
    
    \lipsum[3]
    \nocite{*}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % References %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \begin{thebibliography}{99}
        \bibitem[Ref1, (2003)]{ref1} Ref1 journal, 2003
        \bibitem[Ref2, (2006)]{ref2} Ref2 journal, 2006
        \bibitem[Ref3, (2009)]{ref3} Ref3 journal, 2009
    \end{thebibliography}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: really I'd never do this `\afterpage{\aftergroup\enlargethepage}` and especially in two column mode afterpage explicitly is not supported.

Comment: see page 1 of `texdoc afterpage` ; _This implementation does not work in two column mode_

Comment: Yes @DavidCarlisle, you are right, ```\AtBeginDocument{\shrinkthepage}``` command is executing correctly in two column mode and the page layout seems to be adjusted accordingly, but in one column mode, the text of the article is not placed correctly. As you said, ```\afterpage{\aftergroup\enlargethepage}``` command is not working on the second page, therefore the text height is not adjusted  as expected. Is there a solution?

Comment: Dear @DavidCarlisle, is it possible in any way to check if we are on the second page in the section/subsection environment?

Answer (score 0):

After a few tries myself, I found the solution for one column mode. Considering @DavidCarlisle description about `afterpage`,
I used the

```
\AtBeginDocument{\enlargethispage{-10mm}}
```

command only, instead of

```
\usepackage{afterpage}
\newcommand{\shrinkthepage}{%
\addtolength{\textheight}{-10mm}%
\addtolength{\footskip}{10mm}%
}     
\newcommand{\enlargethepage}{%
    \addtolength{\textheight}{10mm}%
    \addtolength{\footskip}{-10mm}%
}
\newcommand{\restorethepage}{\afterpage{\aftergroup\enlargethepage}}
% hook to shrink text area at start of document
\AtBeginDocument{\shrinkthepage}
% hook to expand text area on page following end of keywords env
\AddToHook{env/abstract/after}{\afterpage{\aftergroup\restorethepage}}
```

for one column mode, I get what I want.

[image: result of one column mode]

But the same technique unfortunately **doesn't work for the two column mode**.

I hope someone finds a solution for this.